# How to add specific values from array list to the Hash map?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, arraylist, hashmap

Here is what I tried:

```
HashMap<String, List<Integer>> hmap = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
List<Integer> valueList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

valueList.add(9);
valueList.add(8);
valueList.add(7);
valueList.add(6);
hmap.put("A", valueList);


valueList.add(5);
valueList.add(4);
valueList.add(3);
valueList.add(2);
hmap.put("B", valueList);


valueList.add(7);
valueList.add(6);
valueList.add(5);
 valueList.add(4);
hmap.put("C", valueList);


valueList.add(2);
valueList.add(3);
valueList.add(4);
valueList.add(5);
hmap.put("D", valueList);
```

When I try to retrieve the values of a specific key from `hmap` by doing this:

```
List<Integer> dimensions = hmap.get("A")
```

I am expecting the hash map to return `[9,8,7,6]` but instead it returns everything in the ArrayList i.e., `[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,7,6,5,4,2,3,4,5]`. How do I make the array list to push only the first values to that key in the `HashMap`? What am I missing?

I also tried `valueList.clear()` after each `hmap.put() statement`. That results in pushing only the last set of values i.e., `[2,3,4,5]` for all the keys in the  `HashMap`.

Comment: You're creating a single list. But you want 4 different lists. That can't be right. If you want 4 different lists, you must create 4 lists, not just one.

Comment: Is there a way to use just 1 list for all 4 keys in hash map?

Comment: Yes, there is. You did that. But of course, if you have one list, it can't contain 4 different sequences of elements. Only one.

Comment: Don't use clone(), that doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @HongyuWang noted

Comment: Also consider using `Arrays.asList()`. Might be easier.

Comment: ...or [List.of()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of(E...))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens because you use the same `valueList` over again and again which continuously updates the values.

Put to each map entry a new separated list.

```
 // ...
 valueList.add(6);
 hmap.put("A", valueList);

 valueList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 valueList.add(5);
 // ...
 valueList.add(2);
 hmap.put("B", valueList);

 valueList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 valueList.add(7);
 // ... etc
```